# Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition suddenly throwing Internal Connection Fatal Errors

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2019, errors

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer edition installed on my computer for local development work with .NET.  Everything was working well as of two months ago, when I was last working on a project that was using it.  I'm finally getting back to the project, but now my program is failing with the following error: "Internal connection fatal error.  Error state 15, Token: 23 (System.Data)".  The program uses a SQL Server authentication account.

I get the same error with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) when I try to connect to the database instance.  It's a saved session to `localhost\MSSQL2019` which used to work.  I get the error whether I use my Windows account or a SQL account.

I updated SSMS to the latest (18.12.1) and still get the error.  I also confirmed the IP settings via the configuration manager.

In frustration, I uninstalled MSSQL 2019 Dev edition, rebooted and tried to reinstall it with a fresh download of the DVD ISO from Microsoft.  The installation gets close to the end, but fails with the same error.

I am able to successfully install MSSQL 2016 Dev edition and connect via SSMS.  However, when I try to upgrade it to 2019, the upgrade completes, but SSMS gets the error again.

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 21H2, 64-bit, with an Intel i7 processor.

I haven't had any luck with Google or Bing to find a solution to this.  Any help is appreciated.

For completeness, here's the full exception.

```
===================================

Testing the registered server failed. Verify the server name, 
login credentials, and database, and then click Test again.

===================================

Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 23 (System.Data)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.NewRegisteredServerForm.testConnection_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: @nateirvin No, I'm not using linked servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encountered the same issue but it is gone since I uninstalled windows update KB5011048

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and through a combination of efforts I managed to resolve it.

1. Run all the uninstallers through Powershell using the following commands twice.

```
$products = Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE (Caption LIKE '%SQL Server 2022%')"
foreach ($product in $products) {
    $guid = $product.IdentifyingNumber
    Write-Host "Uninstalling $($product.Caption) with GUID $guid"
    Start-Process -Wait "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/x $guid"
}
```

2. Running the uninstall for SQL Server from control panel made it realise it was already uninstalled and removed it from the listing.
3. Clearing the Installation paths

- "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
- "C:\Program Files    (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"

4. Clearing the registry of these keys

- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer
- Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
- Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer

5. Restarting
6. Running sfc /scannow & dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
7. Restarting (Again)
8. Using CCleaner to clear out old registry entries
9. Uninstalling KB5011048
10. And finally Restarting

The install then proceeded normally.

Answer (score 1):

My colleagues spent ages trying to sort this one out.  Also tried removing KB5011048 as mentioned above, but it was a full reinstall of the whole PC that finally got it working.

Comment: We have seen the problem even on a clean windows build.

Answer (score 0):

This problem reappeared in VS2022 after upgrading from VS2019.  After spending 2 days trying to find the connection problem, I decided to try VS2019 to publish the same project.  VS2019 worked. My database is local, not in the Azure cloud.

This db connection problem has migrated to VS2022.  I do not upgrade VS for minor "enhancements", so the above update did not affect me until now.  I am using VS2022 - 17.6.4.

VS 2019 - 16.11.26 does not have the problem.  I suspect the VS team is attempting to naïvely connect to the cloud.  And btw, they do this synchronously with a long/indefinate timeout so it is a PITA, requiring killing VS with task manager.

At least now I have a workaround using my old VS2019 for this database-first project.