# SSMS cannot connect to SQL Server 2022 - Internal Error

Tags: sql-server, errors, connectivity, sql-server-2022

I'm trying to connect (on the same host) from SSMS 19.0.2 to a newly installed SQL Server 2022 developer edition instance. I am getting a weird internal error:

```
===================================

Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 23 (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

I found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/317116/microsoft-sql-server-2019-developer-edition-suddenly-throwing-internal-connectio), and the answer suggests uninstalling KB5011048 (.Net Framework 4.8.1), but I do not have that version of .Net installed.

Can someone point out what's wrong?

*Edit:*
I have made some progress. After fiddling with excluded port ranges, I now have SQL Server again listening on the default (1433) port. A Wireshark trace suggested that there was some sort of problem with a TLS handshake, so I changed the connection options to "Encrypt connection" and "Trust Server Certificate". Now I get a connection timeout in the post-login phase.

If I use sqlcmd, the following happens:

```
> .\sqlcmd -S 'tcp:' -N true -C
read tcp 127.0.0.1:55499->127.0.0.1:1433: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
read tcp 127.0.0.1:55499->127.0.0.1:1433: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

In wireshark, I see TDS prelogin messages go back and forth, then the client sends what wireshark describes as a "TLS Exchange", to which the server sends a TCP ACK, and then closes the connection.

Comment: The problem also occurs irrespective of using SQL or Windows authentication.

Comment: have the exact same error on a Windows 0 PC with SQL Server 2022 and SSMS 19.1. Any progress on this one @mikb?

Answer (score 0):

I found this and thanks to the edit realised I was playing with my SCHANNEL settings to replicate a customer ssl authentication issue and ended breaking my SQL server access.

Removing the entries for TLS1.2 and TLS1.3 and restarting the computer resolved it.